# Pandas - string replace but element is a list of strings

Tags: pandas

This line lets me replace the substring `/data/` in every row of the column `path` with `"../datasets/"`

```
 df['path']=df['path'].astype(str).str.replace("/data/","../datasets/")
```

What if every row of the column `path` contains a list of strings e.g. `["/data/1","/data/2"]` ? How can I use replace?

for example `df['path'][0]` should go from `["/data/1","/data/2"]` to `["../datasets/1","../datasets/2"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'path': [["/data/1","/data/2"]]
})
df['path'] = df['path'].apply(lambda lst: [s.replace('/data/', '../datasets/') for s in lst])
```